# Style HTML form to place elements next to each other

Tags: html, css, forms, styling

I am trying to make a set of input boxes next to each other and I can't get it to work. I am trying to get the left side to stay on the left side and the right side to be even with the left side. Below is the HTML and CSS I have so far. I have tried doing the position left and right and they just stay the way they are.

[image]

```css
.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Begin left side data entry -->
    <form>
      <!-- Form tag is only used to allow the Clear button at the bottom to clear the data entry area. -->
      <div class="cell" style="padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;display:block;">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">LH</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q1" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q1',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Node</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q2" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q2',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell"># of Devices offline/Total Devices</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q3" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q3',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">% Offline</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q4" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q4',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Power Supply</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q5" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q5',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">SNR</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q6" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q6',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Dispatched or CBT</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q7" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q7',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Tech Phone #</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q8" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q8',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">ETA</div>
          <div class="cell"><input type="text" id="Q9" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q9',this.value);" /></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Address Block</div>
          <div class="cell"><textarea style="height: 100px;" input type="text" id="Q10" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q10',this.value);"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Individual Addresses</div>
          <div class="cell"><textarea style="height: 100px;" input type="text" id="Q11" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q11',this.value);"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">Ping Stats</div>
          <div class="cell"><textarea style="height: 100px;" input type="text" id="Q12" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q12',this.value);"></textarea></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="cell">SNR</div>
          <div class="cell"><textarea style="height: 100px;" input type="text" id="Q13" onChange="myLHDesc();store_value('Q13',this.value);"></textarea></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="cell" style="text-align: center;"><input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick "myLHDesc();" /></div>
      </div>
  </div>
  </form>

  <!-- Right side for result box -->
  <div class="cell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 650px; float: left;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Notes:</div>
      <div class="cell"><textarea id="LHDesc" rows="20" cols="49" style="overflow: scroll; width: 300px;" readonly></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cell" style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" value="Copy Notes" class="CopyDesc" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Notification Box -->
  <div class="cell" style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 650px; float: left;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">Notification:</div>
      <div class="cell"><textarea id="LHDesc2" rows="10" cols="49" style="overflow: scroll; width: 200px;" readonly></textarea></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="cell" style="text-align: center;"><input type="button" value="Copy Notification" class="CopyDesc2" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Melissa, thank you for your first contribution. To get (more) attention and answers it would be great if you could create a runnable code snippet. That's quite easy to achieve. Just edit your question and use the wizard to do so. Furthermore, please reduce the complexity of the HTML. It is quite difficult to read with all the attributes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

display : flex on the parent div or display : inline-block on the child input elements will position elements next to each other

Comment: Thank you for your help I ended up turning them into tables and that worked